# Copy Random Bytes to Clipboard on OS X

Tags: macos, encoding, clipboard

I'm working on a challenge on [Over The Wire](http://overthewire.org/wargames/narnia/), and I can't even get past the first one because I can't copy arbitrary bytes to the OS X clipboard. I'm trying to use this command to copy the data to my clipboard:

```
echo -ne "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xde" | pbcopy
```

Then, I ran `pbpaste | xxd` to check if it copied correctly:

I expected to get this output:

```
00000000: 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
00000010: 4141 4141 efbe adde                      AAAA....
```

But instead, this is what was copied:

```
00000000: 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
00000010: 4141 4141 c394 c3a6 e289 a0ef ac81       AAAA..........
```

I tried using `echo -ne "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xde" | LANG=C pbcopy`, `LANG=C pbpaste | xxd`, and `pbpaste -Prefer txt | xxd`, but non of those worked either. How can I get OS X to not mess with what I'm copying?

**Edit**

It turns out the problem is with `pbpaste`. I was able to use pbpaste to get the right output using `LANG=MACROMAN pbpaste`, but I still need a way to do this without the command line. So I need a way to paste in other encodings using `cmd+v`.

**Edit 2**

It turns out the problem is iTerm 2's character encoding setting. I changed it to `Western (Mac OS Roman)` and then tried it again, using `cmd+v` to paste. I got this output, which is sooooo close:

```
00000000: 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
00000010: 4141 4141 efbe ad                        AAAA...
```

I'm just missing one byte now! It sounds like I need to find an encoding where all possible sequences of bytes are valid. I thought this was the case with Mac OS Roman, but it doesn't seem so here.

Answer (score 1):

So close! I checked:

```
echo -ne "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xde" | xxd
```

Did you try:

```
echo -ne "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xde" | pbcopy
LANG=C pbpaste | xxd
```

or

```
echo -ne "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xde" | pbcopy ; LANG=C pbpaste | xxd
```

All of these worked in Terminal with OS X El Capitan and bash. I got:

```
0000000: 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
0000010: 4141 4141 efbe adde                      AAAA....
```

Comment: That's very weird, that's not working for me. I'm also on El Capitan, and I'm getting the same result I was earlier. I tried several different shells, and different terminal clients.

Comment: I'm using the U.S. keyboard, could switching the keyboard help?

Comment: Oh I found this http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120114032406552 and apparently I needed to use `LANG=MANROMAN pbpaste | xxd` to paste it. But I still have the problem that I can't just paste this where ever I want. It has to be part of a command...

Comment: Some shells use built-in `echo` commands that don't support the -e or -n options. The zsh shell works without the -e option. The sh and ksh shells don't work. It's expected that different terminal applications behave differently, and it's true that you can't paste anywhere and preserve the binary characters. The encoding setting in use affects how the clipboard is interpreted. Each application has its own defaults and settings. Have you tried `printf "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xde" | xxd` with other shells? Keyboards are not an issue.

Comment: Yes, it works in zsh, which I'm using. I updated the question because I got pbpaste to work right by using `LANG=MACROMAN pbpaste`, but I still need to be able to paste it without relying on the `pbpaste` command.

Comment: Don't use `pbpaste` to paste the clipboard. That's not what it does. The `pbpaste` command copies the clipboard to standard output. Paste the clipboard with Edit->Paste or Cmd-V. The application you paste into determines how to interpret the contents of the clipboard. If the application interprets the clipboard as UTF-8, the binary characters will not be preserved, instead they will be translated to Unicode. If the application is set for Mac OS Roman, the binary characters are (generally) preserved. Would it help if I change the answer to explain our comments?

Comment: Thanks, yeah that'd be great. Do you know of any encodings that guarantee  the binary data will be preserved? Like an encoding where all possible combination of bytes are valid?